# When should I use a JavaScript array in lieu of a JavaScript object literal?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, queue, hashtable

This question may seem trivial but it's something that's been bothering me for a while so I thought I'd ask. Apologies in advance if this question seems silly/naive to you.

So in JavaScript, object literals {} are hash tables under the hood. Meaning that they have near constant time lookup and insertion. So the question I keep wondering is (outside of pure convenience) why would I ever use a JavaScript array in lieu of an object literal?

Take this example of creating a Queue in JavaScript;

1) First, we'll use an Object literal as our storage component;

```
var Queue = function() {
    this.storage = {};
    this.order = [];
    this.length = 0;

    this.add = function(item) {
        this.storage[item] = 1;
        this.order.push(item);
        this.length++;
    };

    this.remove = function() {
        var removed = this.order.shift();
        delete this.storage[removed];
        this.length--;
        return removed;
    };

    this.contains = function(value) {
        return this.storage[value] ? true : false;
    };

    this.size = function() {
        return this.length;
    };
};
```

2) Second, using an array as our Queue's storage component

```
var Queue2 = function() {
    this.storage = [];

    this.add = function(item) {
        this.storage.push(item);
        return this;
    };

    this.remove = function() {
        return this.storage.shift();
    };

    this.contains = function(target) {
        var clone = this.storage.slice(0);
        clone.sort();

        var recurse = function(low, high) {
            if (high === low) return false;
            var mid = Math.floor((high - low) / 2) + low;

            if (clone[mid] === target) return true;
            else if (clone[mid] > target)
                return recurse(low, mid);
            else if (clone[mid] < target)
                return recurse(mid + 1, high);
        };

        return recurse(0, clone.length);
    }
};
```

lets create two separate Queues;

```
var objQueue = new Queue();
var arrayQueue = new Queue2();
```

Now lets add 1 million random passwords to both our Queues.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    objQueue.add(Math.random().toString(36).slice(2));
}
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    arrayQueue.add(Math.random().toString(36).slice(2));
}
```

Normally we would never have to do this all at one time. But yes, it's going to take a little longer to fill up our object Queue. We've had to create a separate array in our Queue constructor to keep track of the order. Yes, this is very annoying. Unfortunately, when adding keys as numbers to a JavaScript object, JavaScript auto-sorts the numerical keys. So if you add 4, then 6, then 2, then 1. The Object will look like this:

```
{ '1': 1, '2':1, '4':1, '6':1 }
```

and for a Queue, we want it to look like this:

```
{ '4': 1, '6':1, '2':1, '1':1 }
```

NOTE: This is not the case when adding strings. With strings, the order of addition is preserved so creating a separate array to preserve order is unnecessary. I'm not sure if this is intentional or just a mistake? But in this particular case, since we're creating a Queue and order matters, it's annoying. Which could be one reason people might prefer to just use an array for storage in this situation.

Removing from the queue will have the same time complexity in both cases because we're always removing the first value. No big deal there.

But what happens if we want to search our Queue? This probably goes against the nature of what a Queue is supposed to be used for(does it??? I dunno, maybe our Queue is a priority queue, we're tired of waiting, and we want to search where our number is in the queue) but let's just say we want to search this giant Queue we've created.

Lets add a value value to the end of both our Queues that is not random:

```
objQueue.add('bvflq9kk61xajor');
arrayQueue.add('bvflq9kk61xajor');
```

Now lets search for this value in our array Queue and measure the time:

```
var start1 = new Date().getTime();
var result1 = arrayQueue.contains('bvflq9kk61xajor');

var end1 = new Date().getTime();
var time1 = end1 - start1;
```

Now lets search for this value in our object Queue and measure the time:

```
var start2 = new Date().getTime();
var result2 = objQueue.contains('bvflq9kk61xajor');

var end2 = new Date().getTime();
var time2 = end2 - start2;
```

RESULTS

```
console.log('Execution time for Array Queue: ' + time1);
console.log('RESULT:', result1);

//Execution time for Array Queue: **3873**
//RESULT: true


console.log('Execution time for Object Queue: ' + time2);
console.log('RESULT', result2);

//Execution time for Array Queue: **0**
//RESULT: true
```

The main reason the array Queue takes so much longer to execute is because I'm having to sort it before performing a Binary Search on it. Binary search is fast but requires the array to be pre-sorted. I could pre-sort the array each time I add a new value to the array Queue but then this would defeat the purpose of what a Queue is: FIFO(first in first out) and we'd start running into the same order issue we have with objects.

So I guess the real question I'm wondering is why do we even bother with arrays when we can do most things we need to do with a JS Object? Especially when JS objects are hash tables and thus we get near constant time lookup with them.

I guess it wouldn't matter so much if you never planned on searching through your data but when is that ever the case?? When you fill up an object or an array with data, you're inevitably going to want to search your data? Yes? No? Am I totally wrong here? And when you go to search this data, you'll be stoked to have stored it in what's essentially a hash table. Right?

Am I totally wrong here? Missing something? Would love some feedback on when to use arrays and when to use object literals. I'm guessing one case would be when your data set is small.

Comment: Lookup by key in an object is fast. However order of traversal of property names is undefined, so arrays are useful in that sense. Also arrays have a `.length` property that makes it fast to determine the size.

Comment: It's easy to keep track of length in objects. Two ways, using Object.keys().length  (which is expensive but works) or by creating a length property in the constructor. Super easy. I'll add that to my implementation now.

Comment: Well you can get *close* to mimicking the behavior of `.length` in arrays, and it may be that you don't really need that exact behavior, but it's actually kind-of hard to really make a non-array work like an Array instance in that regard. See [this slightly old but still interesting blog post.](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/)

Comment: Indexed storage is what makes arrays so useful. You can create multi-dimensional arrays and/or use algorithms to retrieve the specific data you need instead of having to directly reference named values or use a search function. It won't always be the best solution, but I'm glad it's a built in feature, that's for sure. \=)

Comment: "So in JavaScript, object literals {} are hash tables under the hood." - this is not entirely accurate. Implementations vary, but the engine I work on (Chakra) exhibits a degree of polymorphism internally where an object can be both an array and exhibit hashtable behaviour simultaneously under certain circumstances.

Comment: It's a bit of a hack but I am using indexed storage above. I'm just using an array to do it. So yeah, arrays are useful in that sense.  But you  can easily add multi-dimensional arrays within objects as well. Now if I really wanted to take that Queue above to the next level, I could just implement a hashing function for the values which would become my keys. Like so:

Comment: var index = this.hashFunc(key, this.limit);                                                                                 HashTable.prototype.hashFunc = function(str, max) {
  var hash = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var letter = str[i];
    hash = (hash << 5) + letter.charCodeAt(0);
    hash = (hash & hash) % max;
  }
  return hash;
};